# Running minikube on digital ocean and trying to access from outside

Tags: docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean, kubectl, minikube

I installed minikube on digital ocean and now trying to access my application from outside. But somehow its not working.

my service yaml file:

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: python-data-service
spec:
  selector:
   app: python-web-selector
   tier: backend
  ports:
      - port: 5000
        targetPort: 80
        protocol: TCP
  externalIPs:
      - 64.225.117.89
  type: LoadBalancer
```

64.225.117.89 is my droplet ip.

```html
developer@Kubernetes:~/yaml_Files$ minikube service python-data-service
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |        NAME         | TARGET PORT |           URL           |
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| default   | python-data-service |        5000 | http://172.17.0.3:30718 |
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|-------------------------|
  Opening service default/python-data-service in default browser...
```

```html
developer@Kubernetes:~/yaml_Files$ kubectl get services
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes            ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          57s
python-data-service   LoadBalancer   10.111.0.153   64.225.117.89   5000:30718/TCP   16s
sql-python-service    ClusterIP      None           <none>          3306/TCP         15s
```

```html
developer@Kubernetes:~/yaml_Files$ curl http://172.17.0.3:31306
<html>
  <body>
    <form  method="POST" action="/postdata">
      <input type="text" name="student_name">
      <input type="text" name="student_id">
      <input type="text" name="student_email">
      <input type="text" name="student_phone">
      <input type="text" name="student_class">
      <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
  </body>
```

```html
developer@Kubernetes:~/yaml_Files$ curl http://localhost:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

I changed the firewall settings in digital ocean but no luck, Any pointers?

Comment: on droplet you have open port 5000? try sending request on LB IP 64.225.117.89 and port 5000

Comment: Tried with port 5000, still no luck.

Comment: checked firewall and port ?

Comment: yes, opened both inbound and outbound on  port 5000

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to access app in minikube- by NodePort or by LoadBalancer.

Services of [LoadBalancer](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access) type can be exposed via the `minikube tunnel` command. It runs as a process, creating a network route on the host to the service CIDR of the cluster using the cluster’s IP address as a gateway. The tunnel command exposes the external IP directly to any program running on the host operating system. The command currently runs as a separate daemon, and creates a network route to the minikube VM. [It will assign](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/easier-kubernetes-development-from-your-laptop) externalIP to your service and then it can be accessed from your host.

If you want to access it using `NodePort` service type you have to get minikube ip and node port, for example by using `minikube service $SERVICE_NAME --url`.

To access `localhost:node_port` you have to access it from inside of the minikube (`minikube ssh`).